# Is it possible to assign class probability to a random forest prediction?

Tags: probability, random-forest

When making predictions with a random forest model, is it possible to associate the probability of a test case belonging to a class? For example, for a given test case, can we say that the probability of that test case belonging to the `setosa` class is 90%, `versicolor` class is 7% and  `virginica`class is 3%? 
Is there any other way to somehow quantize the association?

```
library(caret)
data(iris); 
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=iris$Species, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[inTrain,]; testing <- iris[-inTrain,]
modFit <- train(Species~ .,data=training,method="rf",prox=TRUE)
pred <- predict(modFit,testing); 


> pred
 [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
[14] setosa     setosa     versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor virginica  versicolor versicolor versicolor
[27] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  versicolor versicolor virginica 
[40] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve probabilities you have to change last line from

```
pred <- predict(modFit,testing);
```

to

```
pred <- predict(modFit,testing,type="prob");
```

However this does not really fit CV site and I believe is more appropriate for SE.